# Run Powershell script as a service, watching log files and reporting via email

Tags: regex, powershell, service, grep

I have some log files that I am watching, I need to do this using PowerShell since its a windows server. the command I am using to do this is:

```
Get-Content System.log -wait | {$_-match "some regex"}
```

I am trying to run this in a script and make it email me if it found any changes to the log file that follow the regex i specify. This is easily doable using bash and cron. I am not sure what's the equivalent in PowerShell. and what return code I need to look for to know if it found anything?

Comment: How fast do you need to know? Do you need to get an email the instance that any new line meets your criteria? Check once every 15 minutes? Once a day?

Comment: email as soon as there is a change

Comment: You need to set up a `FileSystemWatcher` for that. See [here](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b) for sample code.

Comment: This is helpful, but I am not sure how to use it to watch the log. The log file is active and always being written to so there is no point to detect change because I know there is change every minute, all I want to do is look at the change and see if it contains a number that is above a certain threshold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried

```
Get-Content System.log -wait | {$_-match "some regex"} | foreach { send-email -message $_ }
```

I don't know if the result of the where will be piped until get-content -wait exits but give it a go.

As for running it as a service you can call a powershell script from FireDaemon or SvrAny but you could also use a schedule task to keep restarting the script.

Comment: Thats a crafty idea, I will try this and let you know

Comment: This does work!! One problem though, I lose the output that I get from the matcher, do can you pass that to the foreach statement

Comment: should be automatic as the $_ variable see the updated example

Comment: Ah! it was the  $_  that I was looking for. This is my first attempt with Poershell, thanks for the help